# Visual Studio 2017 converting identity error

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I just upgraded my VS 2017 to version 15.5.2, but get the following error dialog every time when open a VSTS project:

> Error converting value "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;xxxxxxxxxx\xxx@microsoft.com" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor' Path 'authenticatedUser.descriptor', line 1, position 184.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the result if you repair your Visual Studio?

Comment: Still got same error message when Sign-in after repair the VS 2017

Comment: Even uninstall and reinstall not help.

Comment: First, try to run `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` to clear user data and try again. (devenv.exe is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE). Secondly, you can upgrade to 15.5.3 and check the result.

Comment: Root cause found with the help of VS team. An old version Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll was added into GAC which caused conflicts. Remove it from GAC resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause with the help from VS team.

An old version Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll was added into GAC which caused conflicts. This assembly should not be in GAC.

After removed this assembly from GAC, the annoying issue resolved.